# Will creatine prevent initial joint soreness when starting exercise?

Tags: creatine, joints, soreness

Currently, I am not taking any performance supplements (creatine/protein). Some of the exercises heaviest on my shoulders are pullups and bench press butterflies with dumbells. Usually, when I start those exercises, the first set or two I have have mild pain in the shoulder joints that feels like I haven't fully recovered from the previous day.

Will taking creatine help recover faster and prevent that pain/soreness? I am a 47 years old male (I understand this type of joint pain comes with age).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creatine does not reduce muscle damage or soreness, or enhance recovery.<sup>[1](https://doi.org/10.1519/r-21076.1)</sup>

If you're experiencing joint pain during initial sets, and it goes away as you continue doing sets, that just sounds like you aren't warming up sufficiently. How many warm up sets are you doing prior to these exercises? (Note: General warm-ups performed prior to beginning the exercise don't count. This includes jogging, foam rolling, shoulder circles, band exercises, etc.)

Let's say you were benching 80kg for sets of 5. A proper, exercise-specific warm up might look like doing sets of 5 reps of bench press using the empty bar, then 40kg, then 60kg.

Comment: I don't warm up at all. I do 5 sets of 10 flies with 60 lb dumbells.

Comment: That's probably it then. Try doing several sets with lighter weights prior to your first work set, gradually working up to the weight you intend to use. For pull-ups, warm-up options include band-assisted pull-ups, a weight assisted pull-up machine if available, or lat-pulldowns with a light weight.

Comment: I don't have lighter weights because I work out at home. 60 lbs is all I have. But it doesn't bother me so much. I just have to tough it out the first set. I thought creatine would help

Comment: In that case you can make flies easier by bending your elbows more, so your arms aren't fully outstretched at the bottom.

Comment: @amphibient Warm up with some push ups then.